# The Apache service named reported the following error: Unable to open logs

Tags: apache, tomcat, windows-services

SAS Foundation runs on Tomcat servers. When I try to restart the Tomcat Apache service on the machine I get the following message

[image]

I opened Windows Event Viewer to see the log. It relates to Apache with the error message:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:   Unable to
> open logs     .

I get no other information here. I assume Tomcat is running on Port `80`.
When I do a `netstat` on my cmd, I see `0.0.0.0:80` taken by TCP. Could this be the conflict?

Would appreciate any help!

**Update:**
I realized actually get 4 logs with every restart attempt. Here are the other three:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error: (OS 10013)An
> attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
> permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80     .
>
> The Apache service named  reported the following error: (OS 10013)An
> attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
> permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80     .
>
> The Apache service named  reported the following error: no listening
> sockets available, shutting down     .

Comment: Port 80 is already taken, try running `netstat -nab` from elevated cmd to see which executable is listening on 80

Comment: @dusan.bajic it's TCP listening on that port.

Comment: No,TCP is protocol. Executable is in the next line below `TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`

Comment: @dusan.bajic we ended up disabling IIS. But thanks for your response. There was no clear way of knowing that it was IIS that used port 80.

Comment: I have the same problem with completely different software, web interface for Marvell RAID controller. It runs for some period of time. Then shuts down with exactly same message. I will search for resolution and will post answer here, if resolved. In my case, IIS is not installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with completely different software, web interface for Marvell RAID controller. I tried several recipes including modifications to `httpd.conf` to no avail. Next, I discovered nearby messages in windows log like follows:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>
> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8845

Thus, logs were not available not because of any errors in `httpd.conf` but simply because Apache was already running but not responding to windows service manager.

I went to task manager and found there relevant `httpd` process running. I killed this process. Then service started normally from service manager without any errors.